# How to create DataGrid in Flex with different value types in rows?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, mxml, flex-spark

I want to create the DataGrid like that:

```
{Label} {TextInput}

{Label} {ComboBox}
```

I can use "ComboBoxGridItemEditor" and etc but problem is that ItemEditors and renderers apllies to the whole column. But I need different types of controls in the different rows but in the same columns.

For better understanding I did screenshot from VS for example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaAAg.jpg]

I want to create properties table like that by MXML because I want to make easier future editing of this table.

Have someone similar task or any ideas how to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a factory function to create itemRenderers depending on data for a given row. Take a look at [itemRendererFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/gridClasses/GridColumn.html#itemRendererFunction).

Example from [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS77c1dbb1bd80d3836ecbb5ec129ec77b1e1-8000.html):

```
private function selectRenderer(item:Object):ClassFactory {
    var classFactory:ClassFactory;
        if(item is IVisualElement){ 
            // If the item is a Flex component, use DefaultComplexItemRenderer.
                classFactory = new ClassFactory(DefaultComplexItemRenderer);
        }
        else if (item is Object){
                // If the item is an Object, use MySimpleItemRendererFunction.
                classFactory = new ClassFactory(MySimpleItemRendererEmployee);
        } 
        return classFactory;
}
```